# Using another connection instead of the default connection throughout the DAG

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow in Google Composer. By default all the tasks in a DAG use the default connection to communicate with Storage, BigQuery, etc. Obviously we can specify another connection configured in Airflow, ie:

```py
task_custom = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='task_custom_connection',
    gcp_conn_id='my_gcp_connection',
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": 'SELECT 1',
            "useLegacySql": False
        }
    }
)
```

Is it possible to use a specific connection as the default for all tasks in the entire DAG?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Specify *gcp_conn_id* via *default_args* in DAG (as Javier Lopez Tomas recommended) doesn't work completely. The Operators that expect gcp_conn_id as parameter works fine, but in my case unfortunately most of interactions with GCP components do so via clients or hooks within PythonOperators.

For example: If I call DataflowHook (inside a function called by a PythonOperator) without specifying the connection, it internally uses "google_cloud_default" and not "gcp_conn_id" :(

```py
def _dummy_func(**context):
    df_hook = DataflowHook()

default_args = {
    'gcp_conn_id': 'my_gcp_connection'
}


with DAG(default_args=default_args) as dag:
    dummy = PythonOperator(python_callable=_dummy_func)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use default args:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#default-arguments

In your case it would be:

```
default_args = {
    "gcp_conn_id": "my_gcp_connection"
}

with DAG(blabla)...
```

Comment: Hey! It's a clever approach. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work to me. Most tasks that connect to GCP components do so via clients or hooks within PythonOperators. For example: If I call DataflowHook without specifying the connection, it internally uses "google_cloud_default" and not "gcp_conn_id".

Comment: Yes, this only works for Operators. If you need it for hooks, either you change the name of your gcp_conn_id to google_cloud_default (this is what I have done with AWS) or you create your own version of the hooks, setting as default the value you want

Comment: I changed the default_args to: `default_args = {'google_cloud_default': 'MY_CONNECTION'}`, but when I don't specify the connection in the hook constructor it still takes the default one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that instead of naming your connection 'MY_CONNECTION', you can name it 'google_cloud_default'. But again, using default_args in a DAG file only affects Operators. If you want to use hooks inside python scripts, you have to create your own hook setting as default value 'MY_CONNECTION' for the argument gcp_conn_id, or rename MY_CONNECTION to google_cloud_default